# Is there an API available to access the Google Sheets "Explore" automated insights?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I really like the Google Sheets feature to "Explore" the data (the icon in the bottom right) that provides some auto-generated insights and visualizations based on the data in the sheet.

Does anyone know if Google exposes an API to access this analytics engine?

Comment: Reading on the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6280499?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) for that service it seems like it's only available when seeing the application itself, and considering the kinds of data it displays it'd be complex in an API. You can, however, make a Feature Request for it at [this link](https://issuetracker.google.com) since it seems like something that would be beneficial for developers.